# python: tkinter radiobutton and button set text attribute but shows nothing on Mac

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I was just doing a layout job for my homework. But the text inside the RadioButton or Button doesn't work. This situation only shows on my Mac. I tried run on Win Laptop and it works well. I was wondering if anyone can help me solve this problem.

Here is the Environment Info:

```
PyCharm 2018.2.4 (Community Edition)  
Build #PC-182.4505.26, built on September 19, 2018  
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 x86_64  
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o  
macOS 10.14  
python version: 2.7.10 / 3.7.0(I tried both)
```

And here is the code:

```
# coding:UTF-8

from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Performance Comparison Between DES and RSA Algorithm")
window.geometry("800x500")

# inside
labelTitle = Label(window, text="Performance Comparison Between DES and RSA Algorithm", font=("Arial", 22), height=4)
labelTitle.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=8, sticky=W)
labelInput = Label(window, text="Input:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
labelPassword = Label(window, text="Password:").grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)
entryInput = Entry(window).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
entryPassword = Entry(window, show="#").grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)

# RADIOBUTTON HERE
var = IntVar()
var.set(1)
radioButtonEncrypt = Radiobutton(window, text="Encrypt", variable=var, value=1).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
radioButtonDecrypt = Radiobutton(window, text="Decrypt", variable=var, value=2).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

# BUTTON HERE
submitButton = Button(window, text="Submit").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E)

Label(window, text="======== Result ========").grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
outputLabel_DES = Label(window, text="Output From DES:").grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
outputText_DES = Entry(window).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)
outputLabel_RSA = Label(window, text="Output From RSA:").grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W)
outputText_RSA = Entry(window).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)    

window.mainloop()
```

The result after running is like this：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9cTn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.7.10 is very old.  By default, is uses the buggy tcl/tk supplied by Apple.  One *must* upgrade to tcl/tk 8.5.18 as specified [here](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).  (It is possible that PyCharm takes care of this, but I have no idea.) Or use the 2.7.15 PSF 64-bit installer for 10.9+, which installs a working tcl/tk.  This is described on the same page.

3.7.0 (and 3.6.7 64-bit version) comes with its own tcl/tk (8.6.8), but the latter is also buggy, though it is not nearly as bad.  We are hoping to include something better with the upcoming 3.7.1.  You might try the 3.6.7 32/64 bit installer.

For posted code, please read and follow the [MCVE page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks! It did worked on 3.6.7!!! Also, thanks for reminding me, i 'll keep it in mind.